An error occurs when uploading the tidyverse package to Google Colab: namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.1 is already loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required
When trying to use colab again after few days to write code in R, an error started to occur:
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.1 is already loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required.
This is not only mine problem: my college has stacked with the same problem yesterday.
I have tried many popular ways for RStudio to overcome this problem.

Remove and install again package rlang;
Specifying version of the rlang via
install_version("rlang", version = "1.1.0", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org");
Remove and install again package tidyverse;
Restarting kernel, typing code in another notebook and updating version of R locally.
After use of update.packages(ask = FALSE) catched warning:
Warning message: “package 'rlang' in library '/usr/lib/R/site-library' will not be updated”
detach("package:rlang", unload=TRUE)

I had already forgotten during the day in what order I launched it, but in the end point 6 worked, but only after I did something else, I did not catch what. When I simply launched point 6 nothing happened.
If someone knows, please tell me in what order I most likely reached detach.

It's not really clear exactly what your question is, but a possible issue is that you are trying to resolve this while rlang is already attached, and you can't always update/remove a package that's in use. For example, devtools::install_version (your step 2) will import rlang into the namespace making it unable to be updated. The most likely solution is to just run install.packages("rlang") in a fresh session, since that won't invoke any other non-base packages and will install the latest CRAN version.

Same problem here. Did the Google Colab team update something and break it?
